# Diagonal dashed line in array

Tags: arrays, line

I would like to have a diagonal dashed line in an array cell. In the example, it should replace `\ddot`. For me, `\ddot` is inconvenient since I already use dots with different meaning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
    +&+&+&&&&\\
    \cdot&\cdot&-\\
    +&+&+&&&&\\ 
    &&&\ddots&&\\ 
    &&&&\cdot&+&-\\ 
    &&&&\cdot&+&-\\ 
    &&&&\cdot&+&- 
\end{array}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use the `$$  $$` construct in LaTeX, use `\[ \]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    $$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
    +&+&+&&&&\\
    \cdot&\cdot&-\\
    +&+&+&&&&\\ 
    &&&\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [dashed] (0.0,1.0) -- (1.0,0.0);
        \end{tikzpicture}&&\\ 
    &&&&\cdot&+&-\\ 
    &&&&\cdot&+&-\\ 
    &&&&\cdot&+&- 
    \end{array}$$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's possible with `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{NiceMatrix}
+&+&+&&&&\\
\cdot&\cdot&-\\
+&+&+&&&&\\ 
&&&\Ddots[line-style=dashed]&&\\ 
&&&&\cdot&+&-\\ 
&&&&\cdot&+&-\\ 
&&&&\cdot&+&- 
\end{NiceMatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: As the package name suggests: **nice**.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Totally true :-)

Answer (score 2):

With `pstricks` and a simpler  `matrix` environment:  make  the last + in the third row and the first + in the fifth  `\rnode` and connect them by a dashed line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

    \[ \begin{matrix}
    +&+&+&&&&\\
    \cdot&\cdot&-\\
    +&+&\rnode{A}{+}&&&&\\
    &&&&&\\
    &&&&\cdot&\rnode{B}{+}&-\\
    &&&&\cdot&+&-\\
    &&&&\cdot&+&-
\end{matrix}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed, linewidth=0.4pt, dash=2.5pt 2.5pt, nodesep=2pt]{A}{B}
 \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]